# Is Zookeeper a fit for this scenario?

Tags: architecture, hadoop, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper

Here's my requirement.

I have got a bunch of machines in a cluster ( say about 4 - A,B,C,D).

A's job is to poll a database for updates (so, A could be looking for new orders in order table). 
 Once, A receives an update, it verifies which one of B,C,D is relatively free (load balances is the right word I guess). It then orders one of B,C,D to start processing the order. A keep tracks of which order is being processed on B/C/D.

B,C,D are like slaves - they only receive updates from A and notify A, when they are done with order processing. If A goes down (due to network issue or something), One of B,C,D would become a master and perform duties of A. A's metadata about what jobs are running is also periodically backed up to a backup node E. So when B/C/D becomes the new master, it would read metadata from E.

I know it sounds a bit like hadoop, but the order processing cannot fit into a map reduce model, so I am looking for ways to leveraging other frameworks like ZooKeeper which can help with the coordination between A,B,C and D.

Is ZooKeeper a fit here?

Answer (score 11):

Zookeeper is a natural choice for coordination problems.

Following recipes can be used for your use cases.

> A's job is to poll a database for updates (so, A could be looking for new orders in order table). 
>   Once, A receives an update, it verifies which one of B,C,D is relatively free (load balances is the right word I guess). It then orders one of B,C,D to start processing the order. A keep tracks of which order is being processed on B/C/D.

[Distributed Queue](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/recipes.html#sc_recipes_Queues) can be used for task scheduling.

> B,C,D are like slaves - they only receive updates from A and notify A, when they are done with order processing. If A goes down (due to network issue or something), One of B,C,D would become a master and perform duties of A.

Looks like a [leader election](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection) problem

> A's metadata about what jobs are running is also periodically backed up to a backup node E.

You can use zookeeper for storing metadata.

Comment: the problem with these examples/recipes is that most of them are stuff I can't relate to. For instance, there is this example that talks about how you should setup a watcher in zookeeper and all that, but hardly something that actually does something on all those nodes (a simple computation or db access or something).

Comment: Jay, I have a similar application to yours (A needs to know which machines, B,C, or D took the job. So we what we end up doing is the following: Write a job with a unique ID to the queue and sets a watcher on it. B,C, or D grabs the job, and then creates a new node called /jobs/uniqueID (atomically, if possible) along with some data saying which machine has it. A is alerted via the watcher that the job is off the queue, and can then address /jobs/uniqueID directly to see who's working on it (if that indeed is important to you).

Answer (score 3):

Zookeeper is a good fit for cluster synchronization (e.g. master selection). Another related (sub-project of Zookeeper) that can help you is [bookkeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/bookkeeper/docs/r4.0.0/bookkeeperOverview.html)

Note that hadoop doesn't use zookeeper (version 0.23 does but it isn't released yet) - HBase does use it even in current and previous versions

Comment: `version 0.23 does but it isn't released yet` - 0.23 has been [released](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/releases.html#11+Nov%2C+2011%3A+release+0.23.0+available) a month back - still in alpha though

Comment: alpha = isn't released yet :)

Comment: alpha = alpha "release" - technically, a release ;-)

Comment: @Jay whatever :).Anyway if you're looking to use zookeeper you probably want to look at Netflix's curator library which makes it easier to use  http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/11/introducing-curator-netflix-zookeeper.html